# Hibernate delete query is not working?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I use the following code to delete a record from table. I was able to successfully insert data to that table. But this delete operation does not work.

```
 @Override
    public int deleteButterflyCountData(int recordId) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        String query = "delete FROM ButterflyCountData where record_id="+recordId+"";
        Query q = session.createQuery(query);
        int result = q.executeUpdate();
        session.close();
        return result;
    }
```

`result` also returns 1 but data table record is not be deleted. What is the issue in here?

Comment: I don't know how your getting result. Your query have syntax error... FORM is not valid with delete query... If you getting result then commit your session before close....

Comment: He is not using `FORM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [commit the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396563/does-hibernates-session-close-automatically-rollback-uncommitted-transactions):

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
...
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 HQL Delete Query Example
Delete a stock where stock code is “7277”.

Query query = session.createQuery("delete Stock where stockCode = :stockCode");
query.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");

int result = query.executeUpdate();


Query query = session.createQuery("delete Stock where stockCode = '7277'");

int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Tried in all ways. Still has the same problem

Comment: On top of syntax error you are not committing transaction if you ever get that far

Answer (score 0):

I replaced :

```
@Transactional
public void deleteCustomer(Long customerId) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query<Customer> query= currentSession
            .createQuery("DELETE FROM Customer c where c.id =:customerId", Customer.class);
    query.setParameter("customerId", customerId);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

with:
I also had the same issue with hibernate 6. You can do this way even if it adds a query:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteCustomer(Long customerId) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.remove(currentSession.get(Customer.class, customerId));
}
```