# hibernate Session.save() without commiting ,returns me the object in session while fetching

Tags: java, hibernate, session, struts-1

In  Hibernate after `session.save(obj)` without committing the transaction. If I close the session, when I try to fetch, I will get the data which is in session, i.e the object I didn't commit including that

```
public static void insert() {
    Session session = Hibernateutil.getSessionFactory().openSession;
    Leave leave = new Leave();
    leave.setUser("nat");
    session.save(leave);
    session.close();
}

public static List fetch() {
    Session session = Hibernateutil.getSessionFactory().openSession;
    List li = session.createQuery("from Leave").list();
}
```

Comment: Any changes in the database after `save()`?

Comment: i have checked in database ,this object is not saved.but while fetching it is showing this object.i have set the isolation level to 2 ,but still no change

Comment: My code

Session session=Hibernateutil.getSessionFactory().openSession;

Leave leave=new Leave();
leave.setUser("nat");
session.save(leave);
session.close();
List li=session.createQuery("from Leave").list();

Comment: You could have managed to search SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275928/hibernate-session-save-does-not-reflect-in-database

Comment: i dont have problem with saving data,i just want to know ,the object which i created when not stored in database why is this reflecting in my new query?

Comment: the object which i created and saved in session ,when will this object will be removed from session?

Comment: First of all create new session....

Comment: i am getting new session from hibernateutil class every time.see my code.

Comment: I'm not able to see new session for fetching data in your code. You're using the same old session.

Comment: the line List li=session.createquery is written in different class not same class/method

Comment: Then post your complete code for better understanding. And do not post your code in comment. Click on edit link underneath your post & then do the changes.

Comment: @user3355121 no you do not creating new session or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Did you check the isolation level. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

Comment: sorry i posted my complete code

Comment: i set the isolation level to 2.

Comment: can anyone try in there IDE the same way i have Written and test the output

Comment: sure, if you provide SSCE

Comment: you just write two methods and try to call them do hardcoding, run as desktop application.

Comment: i got the output correctly if i remove the line session.close();

Comment: does session.close() calls flush inbuilt?

Comment: in hibernate flush means it maps the object in the database with the object in session by studying different documents i got this.but i want to know in depth what the flush means does it maintains physical connection with database or not?