# Can't save object in Hibernate Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate Java . i want to add new object to mySQL. i use save to do it but i can't save object althought i can update. I think i have problem in the hibernate.cfg.xml file but i can't figure it out. i tried the solution in this link

[hibernate session.save() does not reflect in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275928/hibernate-session-save-does-not-reflect-in-database)

i added the line `<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>` to hibernate.cfg.xml but it still is not working. What 's wrong?

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/Checkin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
    <mapping resource="Entities/Teacher.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Entities/Subject.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Entities/Student.hbm.xml"/>
```

This is my subjectDAO , i called it SubjectUtil

```
public class SubjectUtil {
     private final SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    public List<Subject> findSubject()
    {
        List<Subject> list = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        try {
            sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
            list=sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Subject.class).list();
            sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
            return list;

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }finally {
            sf.getCurrentSession().close();
        }
}

      public boolean Save(Subject sub)
      {

          try {
              sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

              sf.getCurrentSession().save(sub);
              sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
              return true;
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
              return false;
          }
      }
      public boolean Update(Subject sub)
      {
          try {
              sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
              sf.getCurrentSession().update(sub);
              sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
              return true;
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
              return false;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Not sure if you can tell since you just rollback your queries and don't actually print/handle the exception.

Comment: @csmckelvey ok, i tried to print out exception but no exception is printed out.

Comment: my guess is  that a record with that key already exists. 
Did you try putting:
   `e.printStackTrace();`
After the 
`catch(Exception e) {` because that should always give you an exception if it fails

Comment: try opening your session first: sf.openSession()
edit: just realised this question is almost 2 years old...

Answer (score 0):

According to hibernate documentation it is not recommended to use `hibernate.connection.autocommit` property:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html