# hibernate session save method not working?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, relation

I 'm new in spring and hibernate. i have a sample project that not work properly. when i try to save new order from user, i get no error or exceprion, but record not inserted into database.
here my code
**strong text**StoreController.java

```
@Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/store/addorder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addOrder(HttpSession session) {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

            // create list of products that we have to add in orders
            List<CartItem> items = (List<CartItem>) session.getAttribute("cart");
            Set<CartItem> itemsSet = new HashSet<CartItem>();

            // new order generated and setter methods invoke
            Orders order = new Orders(itemsSet);
            Date d = new Date();
            Date delivery = StoreUtils.deliveryDate(d, 3);
            order.setOrderDate(d);
            order.setDeliveryDate(delivery);
            order.setItems(itemsSet);

            for (CartItem cartItem : items) {
                itemsSet.add(cartItem);
            }

            String addOrders = orderService.addOrders(order);
            System.err.println("new order add status " + addOrders + "-------------");
            // change product quantity after adding new order

            if (!addOrders.toLowerCase().contains("error")) {

                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    Integer qSale = items.get(i).getQuantity() * (-1);
                    productService.rechargeProduct(items.get(i).getProduct(), qSale);
                }
                model.setViewName("successorder");
                model.addObject("order", order);
                model.addObject("message", addOrders);
                session.setAttribute("cart", null);
            } else {
                session.setAttribute("error", addOrders);
                model.setViewName("redirect:/addtocartlist");
            }
            return model;
        }
```

**Orders.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3672662224925418969L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderid", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    @Column(name = "orderDate", nullable = false)
    private Date orderDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    @Column(name = "delivery", nullable = false)
    private Date deliveryDate;

    @Column(name = "success", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
    private boolean success;

    @Column(name = "cancel", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
    private boolean canceled;

    @Column(name = "cause", nullable = true)
    private String cancelCause;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "ORDERS_ITEMS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "orderid") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item_id") })
    private Set<CartItem> items = new HashSet<CartItem>(0);
//setters and getters
}
```

**CartItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class CartItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7968604053015663078L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int(11) default 1")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "totalprice", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal totalprice;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prd_id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;
//setters and getters
}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7738539408628995177L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "prd_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "seller_name")
    private String seller;

    @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = false)
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "insert_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date insertDate;

    @Column(name = "likes", nullable = true)
    private Integer likeCount;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = true)
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<CartItem> items;

//setters and getters
}
```

and finally here is my doa implementation code

**OrdersDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("ordersDao")
public class OrdersDaoImpl implements OrdersDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session session() {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    }

    public String addOrders(Orders orders) {
        String result = "";

        try {
            session().save(orders);
            result = "success";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("duplicate"))
                result = "error this  order already was exist";
            else
                result = "error " + e.getMessage();
            System.err.println(result);

        } finally {
            session().clear();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

when i try to add new order i get no exception. why my service not work?
i have another controller in my project, that manage users. in that controller and dao implementation add and remove user working properly.
i think i have logic error in my code for one to many and many to many. please help me to overcome this fail.

Comment: Without any exception or description what happens instead (e.g. some logging etc.) and especially that much code it's hard to spot the error and people might not want to dig through your code. Did you try anything to track down the issue yet, e.g. step through your code with a debugger? You also miss some relevant part of your code: you provide the controller and the dao but you seem to have an `OrderService` in between which you didn't show. Please try to post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate session.save() does not reflect in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275928/hibernate-session-save-does-not-reflect-in-database)

Comment: Err, you save an orders, and immediately after, you clear the session, thus cancelling the save you just did.

Comment: Your exception handling is wrong, too: no hibernate exception is recoverable. Stop catching them.

Comment: Hi, I added flush method after save. But again l cannot receive appropriate result.